# Why would a decimal representation of a real number between 0 to 1 not be unique if it ended in all 9s?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is from the cardinality and computability chapter of Epp's Discrete math textbook:

[Excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFphN.png)

Earlier in the chapter, on the same topic, she states: "The resulting decimal representation for P is unique except for numbers that end in infinitely repeating 9’s or infinitely repeating 0’s".

I don't understand why a number encoded in this way ending in infinitely repeating 9s would not be unique. What am I missing here?

Comment: For example, $0.09999\ldots=0.10000\ldots$.

Comment: And just in case that's not enough to convince the OP, we also have (for example) $97.384699999\ldots=97.384700000\ldots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not unique because $0.abc99999999...$ if $c$ is not $9$ too is the same as $0.ab(c+1)000000000000000...$. To prove this, say if that they are not the same, and therefore there is a real number between them (density of real numbers) and it is impossible to find out one that satisfies this condition, so they are the same.